# Cómo puedo manipular un botón de una pagina web que se encuentra en Internet?

Tags: web, google-chrome

No se si existe forma,pero vale la pena intentar, hay una red Wifi a la que me conecto y me envía a una pagina web donde debo dar clic a un botón para que me de acceso a Internet, pero cada 40 minutos toca volver a cargar la pagina principal y dar clic nuevamente al botón.

Me gustaría saber si se puede automatizar este proceso y cargar automáticamente la pagina cada 40 minutos y que se presione el botón de igual forma automáticamente.

Desconozco que tipo de lenguaje tendría que usar para manipular el contenido de la pagina desde mi navegador(puede ser para cualquier navegador), con el cual pueda realizar esta actividad.

Comment: puede ser con firefox y [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) onda https://gist.github.com/damoun/3967968

Comment: Mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Comment: Echa un vistazo también a Puppeteer, permite interactuar con páginas web en segundo plano (es decir, sin abrir ninguna ventana de navegador): https://pptr.dev/